# How to reset the .ftpquota counter on a per user basis for pure-ftpd server

Tags: linux, ftp, quota, pureftpd

I am trying to reset the counter values to 0 in .ftpquota file for all ftp users on a daily basis in pure-ftpd server .

From manual page I got that we can set the quota limits using the "-n" option in pure-ftpd server . But I could not find how to reset this counter value in the .ftpquota file on a daily/weekly basis .

Is there any commands available for the same ? or do we have to manually edit this file ?

Comment: Why would you want to set the counters to zero in the first place? Shouldn't you be running [pure-quotacheck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pure-quotacheck.8.html) from a (weekly) crontab instead? That ensures the correct values are used.

Comment: Hi @HBrujin pure-quotacheck  I am using . But it will just update the quota file based on the current status of the folder(number of files/size) right . I want to reset the counters back to zero irrespective of the current files present in the ftp upload directory . So I am looking fo any commands to reset the counter to 0 , if there are any .